# Can I read a point clouds from a .e57 files without any library?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, e57

The libE57 is okay but I have to try to do this without any library. I found [presentation](https://www.unavco.org/community/meetings-events/2011/tls/presentations/3_Fowler_spie-e57.pdf) and there I found next:

> **Binary Encoding**
>
> **Blobs**  :
>
> - Opaque encoding
> - Images, user-defined data ....

"Opaque encoding" means that I can't read .e57 without libE57?

**Is there some way to parse it?**

I have a parser for a .pcd, .pts, .ptx. Can I convert a .e57 to one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can read data of .e57 only using libe57.

http://www.libe57.org/documentation.html

Comment: Actually, libe57 is the reference implementation (even if I don't any other) for the E2807 spec which described the format - the format spec can be bought, and used to parse e57 files - https://www.astm.org/Standards/E2807.htm

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/asmaloney/libE57Format, it has an alternative implementation that does not rely on Boost, and is used in CloudCompare. The cloudcompare code is at https://github.com/CloudCompare/CloudCompare. It splits the loading code into LoadScan for pointcloud data (see E57Filter) and LoadImage for 2d images. You may have to wrangle yourself through some of the CloudCompare data structures in order to get something decent out of it.